# Readline.completion_append_character doesn't work for irb

Tags: ruby, readline, irb

I built my ruby like so:

```
brew install readline
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/
```

When I do tab completion it appends a space after everything. I found in the docs that there's a variable called `completion_append_character`. It's set to a space. If I set it to nil or any other character it still appends a space. How do I get it to stop appending a space after a completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem is solved in the last version of Ruby 1.9.3-p125 as you can see in [Changelog](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_3_125/ChangeLog):

> Wed Feb  8 10:34:59 2012  TAKAO Kouji
>
> - ext/readline/readline.c (readline_attempted_completion_function):
>     in Readline module with GNU Readline 6 case, Readline module
>     resets completion_append_character to " ", after it executes
>     completion. So, Readline module stores
>     completion_append_character, and Readline module always sets it
>     after Readline module executes completion. [ruby-dev:43456]
>     [Feature #4635]

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue myself, and I figure a late answer is better than no answer.  After doing some research, this is a bug in Ruby or Readline itself, and seems to be present in every revision of Ruby I could find, which makes me think it's Readline.  I was able to solve the problem with a

`gem install rb-readline`

and then

`require 'rb-readline'`

in my script.  Rb-readline (Ruby Readline) is a drop-in replacement, pure Ruby implementation of Readline and does not rely on the C extension, and the `Readline.completion_append_character` variable is functional.